# C# - TextBox does not use recent input

Tags: c#, textbox

```
namespace NewEEDICalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Calculations cal = new Calculations();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            groupBoxResult.Visible = true;
            textShipType.Text = cal.Capacity();

        }
    }
}




public class Calculations
    {



        public string Capacity()
        {

            Form1 f1 = new Form1();

            double DWT = Convert.ToDouble(f1.textDWT.Text);
            double cap;

            switch (f1.textShipType.Text)
            {
                case "CON":
                    cap = 0.7 * DWT;
                    break;
                default:
                    cap = DWT;
                    break;
            }
            string c = cap.ToString();
            return c;
        }

    }
```

My problem is the textbox (textDWT) use its initial value for the calculation not the one that user types in on the Form.

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `Form1` and using that in the calculation, being a new instance it won't have any values typed in. You either need to use the existing instance if there is one, or use `f1.Show();` so they can enter a value.

Comment: Additional to what Equalsk sais: You should avoid a dependency to GUI code in your Calculations class. I suggest altering its signature to `public string Capacity( string shipType , double dwt )`

Comment: Thanks **@Equalsk** & **Fildor** you are enlightened me about this concept. I am sorry to steal your time with that newbie mistake and thank you for your inspiring support again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `Form1` each time when you call `Capacity` as @Equalsk mentioned in the comment.

you could just pass a value of existing textbox:

```
public class Calculations
{
    public string Capacity(double DWT, string shipType)
    {
        double cap;

        switch (shipType)
        {
            case "CON":
                cap = 0.7 * DWT;
                break;
            default:
                cap = DWT;
                break;
        }
        string c = cap.ToString();
        return c;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Calculations cal = new Calculations();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        groupBoxResult.Visible = true;
        double dwt = Convert.ToDouble(textDWT.Text);
        textShipType.Text = cal.Capacity(dwt, textShipType.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for correcting my misperception about this concept. That example solved my problem mentally and physically.